# using Java 8 How to filter by list and group by based on filter condition and convert to Map with their count

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert below for loop to Java 8. But having problem with filtering list of status and grouping into one status and total count.
I tried but for each `"LIVE"`, `"DRAFT"`, `"TEST"` have to loop 3 times and get 3 different maps. Is it possible to get into one loop using Java-8?

Where `"LIVE"`, `"DRAFT"` and `"TEST"` are again combination of status from `workflowInstance` like `DRAFT = {"DRAFT_EDIT","DRAFT_SAVE"}`. I want to categorize all status into 3 based on this combination defined.

```
Map<String, Integer> summaryMap = new HashMap<>();
int l = 0, d = 0, t = 0;

for (WorkflowInstance instance : workflowInstances) {
    if (liveStatuses.contains(instance.getStatus())) {
        summaryMap.put("LIVE", l++);
    } else if (testStatuses.contains(instance.getStatus())) {
        summaryMap.put("TEST", t++);
    } else if (draftStatuses.contains(instance.getStatus())) {
        summaryMap.put("DRAFT", d++);
    }
}
```

Java-8 individually for `"LIVE"`, `"DRAFT"` and `"TEST"`:

```
map.put("DRAFT", workflowInstances.stream()
     .filter(inst-> Constants.DRAFT_STATUS.contains(inst.getStatus()))
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorkflowInstance::getStatus, Collectors.counting()))
     .entrySet().stream().mapToLong(e-> e.getValue()).sum()
);

map.put("LIVE", workflowInstances.stream()
     .filter(inst-> Constants.LIVE_STATUS.contains(inst.getStatus()))
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorkflowInstance::getStatus, Collectors.counting()))
     .entrySet().stream().mapToLong(e-> e.getValue()).sum()
);

// Similar for "TEST"
```

Instead of looping 3 times I want to do in 1 go and categorize them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I think you don't need to filter anything. Just collect groupingBy and thats it - you got a map with status as key and count as value.

Comment: I want to filter as status from workflowInstance object is like DRAF_EDIT, DRAFT_SAVE etc but want to combine them as DRAFT.

Comment: Your `summaryMap` already has this information. Why do you want to do any further processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid extracting the type of the status anyway. Create a dedicated method for it (I suppose the list of statuses as `liveStatuses` etc. are either static or instance variables. Note that you have forgotten to handle the case no one of the predefined statuses match the current one. In that case, let's use `"UNDEFINED"`:

```
String extractStatus(WorkflowInstance workflowInstance) {
    String status = workflowInstance.getStatus();
    if (liveStatuses.contains(status)) {
        return "LIVE";
    } else if (testStatuses.contains(status)) {
        return "TEST";
    } else if (draftStatuses.contains(status)) {
        return "DRAFT";
    }
    return "UNCATEGORIZED";                          // in case nothing is matched
}
```

Then the collecting is fairly easy using `Collectors.groupingBy` with a combination of `Collectors.counting`:

```
Map<String, Long> map = workflowInstances.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                  // groups to Map
            this::extractStatus,                     // extracted status is the key
            Collectors.counting()));                 // value is a number of occurences
```

---

Note the result is `Map<String, Long>` if you insist on `Map<String, Integer>` you need an additional downstream collector using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = workflowInstances.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                   // groups to Map
            Foo::extractStatus,                       // extracted status is the key
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(             // value is collected ...
                    Collectors.counting(),            // ... a number of occurences
                    count -> new BigDecimal(count)    // ... as Integer from Long
                                 .intValueExact()))); // ... but might throw an exception
```

Using The `ArithmeticException` is thrown if the number is outside bounds. Remember that `Long` has the way bigger range than `Integer`. There are many different ways of the conversion of `Long`->`Integer` but they follow the same principle.

... or use a simple trick using `Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)` instead of `Collectors.counting` as [@HadiJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j) suggested. It returns `Integer` instead:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = workflowInstances.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::extractStatus, Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

Comment: In 2nd and 3rd if you got `instance` variable - which isn't declared in that context. Should be changed to `status`.

Comment: instead second way I think you can use `Map<String, Integer> map = workflowInstances.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                  
                        this::extractStatus,                    
                        Collectors.summingInt(e->1)));`

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is to create a more complex grouping function that would transform `getStatus` into one of the three types you want. You could try something like this:

```
Map<String, Long> summaryMap = workflowInstances.stream()
    .groupingBy(a -> {
        if (liveStatuses.contains(a.getStatus())) {
            return "LIVE";
        } else if (testStatuses.contains(a.getStatus())) {
            return "TEST";
        } else if (draftStatuses.contains(a.getStatus())) {
            return "DRAFT";
        }
     }, Collectors.counting());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code: 
My solution add a enum to handle multiple status in different types.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<>();
        instances.add(new Instance("LIVE"));
        instances.add(new Instance("TEST"));
        instances.add(new Instance("TEST"));
        instances.add(new Instance("TEST"));
        instances.add(new Instance("DRAFT"));
        instances.add(new Instance("DRAFT"));

        Map<String, Long> counts = instances.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> TemplateStatus.getStatus(a.getStatus()),Collectors.counting());

        System.out.println(counts);  //output: {DRAFT=2, TEST=3, LIVE=1}

    }



class Instance {
    public Instance(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

enum TemplateStatus {
    LIVE("LIVE,LIVE2"), DRAFT("DRAFT,DRAFT_2"), TEST("TEST_1,TEST");

    private List<String> status;

    TemplateStatus(String s) {
        status = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
    }

    public static String getStatus(String s) {
        if (LIVE.status.contains(s)) return "LIVE";
        else if (TEST.status.contains(s)) return "TEST";
        else if (DRAFT.status.contains(s)) return "DRAFT";
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: `Instance` can have statuses like "DRAFT_EDIT, DRAFT_SAVE" - those would be assigned to "DRAFT" in the result map.

Comment: @Amongalen I solved it using `Enum`. Hope this helps.